# html-mode: add font-lock support for multiple tags

Tags: html

In `html-mode`, how may a user add font-lock support when using multiple tags, such as:

```
<u>Hello <i>foo/bar/baz</i> World</u>
```

In the above-example, the text between the italics tags is italicized, but those italics tags break the font-lock underlining of the entire line.

Comment: In the font-lock keyword, use `append` or `prepend` as OVERLAY flags.

Comment: @Lindydancer -- Thank you for the suggestion. The `defconst` Lisp code for `sgml-font-lock-keywords-2` (in the library `sgml-mode.el`) uses `prepend`, but perhaps the code does not contemplate a nested tags situation such as the example above?

Comment: It could be a problem with how the faces are defined. You can check if there are two faces or just one in the part in the middle, and go from there when tracking down the problem.

Comment: @Lindydancer -- I evaluated the relevant code from the `defconst` named `sgml-font-lock-keywords-2` and came up with:  `("<\\(b\\(?:ig\\|link\\)\\|cite\\|em\\|h[1-6]\\|rev\\|s\\(?:mall\\|trong\\)\\|t\\(?:itle\\|t\\)\\|var\\|[bisu]\\)\\([  ][^>]*\\)?>\\([^<]+\\)</\\1>" 3 (cdr (assoc-string (match-string 1) sgml-tag-face-alist t)) prepend)`  I then took the regexp from that snippet and plugged it into `re-builder` looking at the example in the question above.  The regexp matches only `<i>foo/bar/baz</i>`, not the entire line containing the underline tags on each end.

Comment: @Lindydancer -- the only face present is on the words "`foo/bar/baz`", which is `italic`.  There is no face present on "`Hello`" or "`World`".

Comment: The regexp seems to match `<TAG> "something without a <" </TAG>`. Hence, it will not match <u> and </u>. A better solution would be a rule that match a single tag and then use code to look for the corresponding end tag. It's a bit more work (but, hey, writing font-lock rules are fun!).